# Socket.io connection from localhost

Tags: node.js, socket.io, localhost

I have nodeJs application which is running on server `http://mysite.co:8081`. Where I have chat application. Using `socket.io` for communication.

Now I want to connect to `socket` from `localhost` -- I am trying to connect from my machine where I have wamp installed and in that created one `html` file in `www/test/index.html`.

The `index.html` have below code only.

```
<script src="http://mysite.co:8081/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io('http://mysite.co:8081');
  socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
  });
</script>
```

The `socket.io.js` file is loading correctly, But I am getting below error

`Uncaught TypeError: io is not a function`

Let me now what I am doing wrong.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one:

```
<script src="http://mysite.co:8081/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://mysite.co:8081');
  socket.on('news', function (data) {
   console.log(data);
   socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: The http://socket.io/docs/ saying use io() but io.connect() works. Strange, I will check more and update my findings.

Comment: check the heading carefully...it is mentioned that if you are "Using with Node http server" then go for io() and for "Using with Express 3/4" use io.connect().

Comment: Thanks for identifying -- I am using node as well as express on server. `var socketio = require('socket.io'); var express = require('express');` is that the case to use `connect` method?

Comment: yes...only when you are using basic node server,without any framework,then use io().